# 'dict' object has no attribute 'union'

Tags: python, dictionary, union, corpus

I have wdict as a dictionary and i want to add all unique words to it which are scanned from the text files stored at path and converted to list of words by CleanDoc().
I an getting error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'union'. What should i do?

```
import collections
import os.path
import glob
import nltk

wdict = {}
path = "C://Python27//Corpus Files//*.*"


#this function cleans up a doc (removes stopwords etc)
def cleanDoc(doc):
    stopset = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    tokens = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(doc)
    clean = [token.lower() for token in tokens if token.lower() not in stopset and len(token) > 3 and token.isalpha() and not 'reuter']
    final = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in clean]
    return final

for text in glob.glob(path):
    f = open(text)
    data= f.read()
    words = cleanDoc(data)
    wdict = wdict.union(words)
    print wdict
```

Comment: Take a look at the [dict API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).  There is no `union` method for a `dict`.

Comment: Note that (once you make it a `set`) you will get an `UnboundLocalError` from trying to assign to a `global` without declaring it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) instead of a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
wdict = set() # `wset` will make a better name
```

Also probably `wdict.update(words)` will look better than `wdict = wdict.union(words)`

Comment: To be clear, there is no "empty set literal" in python, so the only way to make an empty set is with `set()`.

Comment: @Nigel Tufnel: `wdict.update(words)` returns `None` so you can't assign it to a variable, whereas `wdict.union(words)` returns the updated set.

Comment: @superjump Yup, so that's why they left off the `wdict =` in front of the `update` call.

Comment: If you change `wdict` from a dict to a set, best to change its name too, having a variable `wdict` which is not actually a dict could be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Python Dictionary object does not have a union method.
As suggested in the error.
Union method is only available over Sets.

You should look at the SO answer :- [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

My favorite is :-

```
       w_dicts.update(words)
```

But this is purely because of personal choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Notice that they are actually using sets, they thought that `{}` created an emtpy set, not an empty dict.  That's really the error here.

Answer (score 0):

Change `wdict = {}` to `wdict = set()`.

Comment: It works but i want to do union of words from all documents like extend or append.